# Using string.Remove('\n') in C# truncates the string at one point

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, replace, ip

I have a string of IP address with a line break.
I need to remove all the line breaks from the literal. So I used string.Remove()

Now once the debugger crosses this line, The result of the expression truncates at "192.168.20"

Why this is happening. I don't want to use Replace, I want to get rid of the '\n'

[image]

Comment: No [`string.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-5.0) method takes a character to remove. I expect it's being converted to an int (`10`)

Comment: Even though it tries to cast as an int, How it truncates at that specific point? I was able to resolve it using   var result = @"192.168.204.18".Replace("\n", "");    but I want to know why string.Remove() is acting weard

Comment: It's not acting weird. Why do you think it's acting weird?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-5.0), you'll see that there isn't actually an overload of `string.Remove` that takes a character to remove.

I expect the `char` is being implicitly cast to an `int` and you're hitting [`string.Remove(startIndex)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-5.0#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_):

> Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted.

`\n` would translate to the character's decimal value, 10, and therefore be passed to `string.Remove` as position 10, so everything after would get removed, which is what we see happening: 192.168.20 is 10 characters long.

If you just want to remove everything after and including the first `\n`, I would suggest something like this:

```
int idx = input.IndexOf("\n", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
if (idx != -1)
{
    input = input.Remove(idx);
}
```

Alternatively to simply replace all of the instances of `\n`, use `replace` (I know you said you didn't want to do this, but just in case):

```
input = input.Replace("\n", string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks .!

Answer (score 1):

String.Remove does not take a character but an index.

`\n` in integer form is `10` so that explains your behaviour.

What you are looking for is something like that:

```
result = input.Replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: _"I don't want to use Replace, I want to get rid of the '\n'"_.

Comment: I clearly mentioned in question and comment I know how to use string.Replace().

Comment: That's exactly what Replace does. It replace the \n with nothing, thus removing it

Comment: I just want to know why it truncates the string at '20' in IP address

Comment: Because Remove takes an `Int32`as parameter, you are giving it a `char` which is implicitly converted to an `Int32` : 10. So it truncates your string at index 10. If you watch the result, you will find that `192.168.20` is exactly 10 characters long.